# Buttons Move When Adding Text Dynamically, How to fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]I am creating an app where I populate the screen with buttons that have letters in them and when a button is clicked the character will appear on another button. When the buttons are initially created they are positioned correctly on the page, but as soon as I add a letter to the button through jQuery, the button that was clicked moves and the button that receives the letter moves as well.

I am wondering how I can fix this. I have tried adding CSS as well as change my HTML layout but nothing seems to have worked.

Here is the HTML code used for the page:

```
<div id="center">
  <h1>Word Game</h1>
  <img src ="" id ="answerImage" alt = "overwatch"/>
  <h2>Inputs</h2>
  <div id="inputs"></div>

  <h2>Scrambled Word</h2>
  <div id="wordScambled"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the code that populates the button with a letter:

```
newWord += '<button class= "character" id =' + count + ' value = ' + count + ' style="width: 45px; height:45px;margin-left: 10px; border: 2px solid #238d9c; border-radius: 5px;background-color: #b4eaea;">' + alphebet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphebet.length)] + '</button>';
```

Then this is used to set the button to have HTML:

```
$("#wordScambled").html($("#wordScambled").html() + newWord);
```

Here is the css:

```
#center{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#wordScambled{
   vertical-align:top;
}
#center img{
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question to show a complete snippet of the problem, including the CSS.

Comment: Also note that there is no `image` element. I assume you meant `<img />` instead

Comment: Your button width `45px` isn't wide enough to accommodate the new text

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very late to the party, but I just encountered this problem as well. No combination of position or display attributes solved the issue. For me, the fix was to simply keep a character in the button at all times. Since javascript strips out space characters, you can't simply do this:

```
btn.innerHTML = " ";
```

But using an invisible character works, such as:

```
btn.innerHTML = '\u2060';
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is because you are adding style to every new word. Try making it separate. Need more images or include the css and the clicking part.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a nested span inside the div#wordScambled  with a display: block with a fixed width to display the letter without shifting when the new letter is added to it.

```
    <style>
#center{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#wordScambled{
   vertical-align:top;
}

#wordScambled > span{
   display: block;
width: 30px;
}
#center img{
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
</style>
<div id="center">
  <h1>Word Game</h1>
  <img src ="" id ="answerImage" alt = "overwatch"/>
  <h2>Inputs</h2>
  <div id="inputs"></div>

  <h2>Scrambled Word</h2>
  <div id="wordScambled"><span></span</div>
</div>

<script>
$("#wordScambled span").html($("#wordScambled").html() + newWord);
</script>
```